# C++ anonymous namespace: Variables initialized to 0?

Tags: c++, static

There is a related unanswered question here:
[c++ - Variables auto-initialized to 0 in unnamed namespace? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526466/variables-auto-initialized-to-0-in-unnamed-namespace)

When I have a global function pointer in C I can declare it static and it's initialized as NULL and only available for my file. In C++ I'm switching a lot of stuff to anonymous namespaces but I'm curious if they hold that same guarantee. If I have a function pointer in an anonymous namespace will it be initialized to null?

Thanks

Comment: Just initialize it yourself to NULL. That is the clearest way.

Comment: No - the "namespace" has nothing to do with it: static storage is always initialized to 0/NULL.  And yes, it's definitely good practice to specify "static struct *myptr = NULL;", just to make your intent explicit.  IMHO...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*All* variables with static storage duration are zero-initialized when the program starts.  These include all variables declared at namespace scope (in the global namespace or in any other namespace, including an unnamed namespace).

Comment: Just to be clear here you are saying that something like `namespace { int var; }` has static storage duration?

Comment: @test: Yes.  Namespaces have nothing to do with it

Comment: ok thanks. I'll mark this as correct after the 10 minute wait period passes.

Comment: "All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are not local have _static storage duration_. [...] The keyword `static` can be used to declare a local variable with static storage duration. [...] The keyword `static` applied to a class data member in a class definition gives the data member static storage duration." _— [basic.stc.static] 3.7.1_