# How anonymous namespaces avoids making global static variable?

Tags: c++, namespaces

We can have anonymous namespaces (namespace with no name). They are directly usable in the same program and are used for declaring unique identifiers. It is said that it avoids making global static variable.My question is if it is not static then why default value is zero?

As these question has been asked before but  it is not  clear at all [C++ anonymous namespace: Variables initialized to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609690/c-anonymous-namespace-variables-initialized-to-0)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace 
{
  int x; // Here x should have garbage value according to definition of anonymous namespace
}

int main()
{
   cout << x << endl;// But x is throwing zero why?
}
```

Comment: It still has static storage duration (which means zero-initialization). It just makes it impossible for other TUs to access things with external linkage. I'm not sure what's unclear in the link.

Comment: @chris Then there is no difference between anonymous namespace and namespace with name?

Comment: Not for storage duration. If you have a function (or extern variable etc), a named namespace would make it easy for another TU to use that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you incorrectly understand the phrase

> It is said that it avoids making global static variable

or the phrase itself is confusing.

In this phrase word `static` means internal linkage. For example if you will write

```
namespace N // named namespace
{
   static int x;
}
```

then variable x will have internal linkage. it will not be visible outside the compilation unit where it is defined. Or each module that will contain this definition will have a separate object with name x.

To achieve the same effect you could place its definition in an unnamed namespace. In this case according to the C++ 2011 Standard it will also have the internal linkage.

```
namespace // unnamed namespace
{
   int x;
}
```

At the same time any object defined in a namespace has static storage duration. It means that it will be initialized. For fundamental scalar types the initialization is the zero initialization.

Answer (score 5):

The anonymous namespace doesn't really prevent names from becoming global names! In fact, a compiler may create object files which define the symbols as global symbols. However, the anonymous namespace basically hides these global names away with a name which can only be referred to from one translation unit.

The zero initialization applies to all objects with static storage duration. All variables at namespace level, including the anonymous namespace and function local `static` variable have static storage duration unless they are declared `thread_local`.

Comment: kuhl please can u explain with example i am unable to figure out it?

Comment: @BECOOL: example of what?

Comment: kuhl I mean Can you please explain difference between anonymous namespace and namespace with name with example or else i have to go for bounty?

Comment: @BECOOL: just think of anonymous namespaces as being named namespaces but with a name you can't spell explicitly. When you look at the symbols in an object file (e.g. on UNIXes using `nm -po file.o`) may see what the compiler actually generated. The compiler may also use local symbols for variables, though, but this doesn't change that the object has static linkage and gets zero initialized.

Comment: @BECOOL You should consider accepting **this** answer instead.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou ya  as i am new to programming i understand easy explained with example so please never mind hope you can understand